# How to set a form as the Main Loading form Windowsforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one form let's call it registration which i created first, I now have a second form lets call it menu. I know these were created the wrong way around but now when i run my Win-forms application it only ever loads the registration form , i am trying to switch my Menu form to be the main loading form (to which i will add a function/button to then load the registration form). I have tried looking in the panel to perhaps set a parent/child relationship cant but find anything

Answer (score 1):

In the `Program.cs` there is a method called `Main`.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
    //                  ^^^^^
}
```

Change the `Form1` to the other form you wish to create at startup.

Comment: Damn so simple thank you so much!